# Which css grid system should I learn?

Tags: css, css-frameworks, grid-system

#### Duplicate

> [What is the best CSS Framework and are they worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069)
> [Can someone Recommend a Bells and Whistles CSS framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322484)
> [Help me choose a CSS framework: 960 vs Blueprint vs ???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589184)
> [Best CSS Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639285)
> [How do you choose a CSS Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647853)
> [What is the best CSS GridFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996)

I started off using [Blueprint CSS](http://blueprintcss.org/) but have been hearing lots of things about [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) and [Yahoo! Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/).

I can't seem to get a good handle on which one to use (or why).

I am looking for any advice about which grid system I should use. Ease of use, flexibility and code readability are important to me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069, 322484, 589184, 639285, 639299, 647853, 76996...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used YUI Grids on several sites and found it, in combination with the Fonts and Reset components, to provide very high quality cross browser compatible sites. It's design satisfies different goals to 960.gs and a quick look at your site's storyboards will indicate which is more appropriate.

YUI Grids can be nested achieve subdivison of elements and generally I find it easy to work with.

I'd say that use of a reset css is *crucial*, and work with whatever grid system you find most comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

[I asked a similar question a while back.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort)

In terms of my own experiences since then, I've abandoned the whole css framework/grid systems. I did try Yahoo Grids in anger, it is far too inflexible. I felt BluePrint was much better.

But as the answer to my question pointed out, css frameworks and grids miss the point about the problems CSS is addressing.

Comment: I think the response to your question applies more heavily to 960.gs than to YUI. While the points made are fair, YUI's markup is semantic, lightweight and generally just provides container elements (i.e. a main content area, left/right col, header and footer).

Comment: The reason I found YUI grids inflexible was that if you don't use one of the default styles, you can get into situations where you might need to nest a couple of levels. (see http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/grids/grids-gg.html) For me, YUI grids didn't seem flexible enough.